# Mirror Image in UITableView cell for Localization

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: images in cells are not flipped]

I need to flip the arrow image in `UITableview` cells. I am trying to use `flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection` 
but it's not giving the mirror effect.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    cell.imageViewArrow.image?.withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()
} 
else {
    cell.imageViewArrow.image =   UIImage(cgImage: (cell.imageViewArrow.image?.cgImage!)!, scale:(cell.imageViewArrow.image?.scale)! , orientation: UIImageOrientation.upMirrored)
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

Comment: could you please add screenshot of cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the image to anything. Replace your code with this:

```
cell.imageViewArrow.image = cell.imageViewArrow.image?.withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation()
```

However, it's recommended to set the flipped image only when the language is RTL. For this, set the image to the return value of `imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection()`:

```
cell.imageViewArrow.image = cell.imageViewArrow.image?.imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set image's `language-direction` from `Images.xcassets` folder as follows 
[image: Images.xcassets here]

and it will show proper flipped image for `RTL` layout and the actual image for `LTR` layout.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/ImageSetType.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015170-CH25-SW32